# PhpStorm & Git on remote server

Tags: git, version-control, phpstorm

I am new to Git and PhpStorm. Maybe I am on the wrong track here, but I would like to use my remote webServer, where my web application is hosted, also as development server. ( to be sure to have the exact same webserver config and version )

Is there a way to deploy different git branches to different folders, in order to make them accessible via the webserver.

Let's say I have a branch 'NewFeatures' and a branch 'BugFixes', then I would like to be able to access both branches by two different Urls, like 'http://foo.bar/versions/NewFeatures' and 'http://foo.bar/versions/BugFixes'.

What is the best way to do that ( with PhpStorm ) ?
Or do I put the cart before the horse here ?

Comment: git branches is help you to develop your code concurrently, and different branches have different working directories. They have the same URL, such as the repo name is `repo`, both the URL will be  `http://foo.bar/repo`.

Comment: No they don't, at least not on my setup ?! When I create a branch, there is no new directory created ? What am I missing ?

Comment: I meant git working directory (it's different from directory we usually speaking), it's a section for git repo (you can refer https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics). When you switch to other branches, files will also checkout to the related branch.

Comment: Yes, exactly. As there is no 'real' directory for each branch, there is no way that the webserver can access both of them ?!

Comment: Yes, it can only shows for a branch for a time. If you need to show files from the two branches, you can merge them into a branch.

Comment: So, in other words, if I want to 'run' a certain branch trough a webserver, I need to setup a local webserver pointing to the project directory and checkout to the desired branch. When everything is fine, merge to master and upload to production webserver. Is there no way to do this without local webserver ?

Comment: I don't know what's your exact code, but usually it's just need to run on phpstorm. If it's successful, you can merge your code with another branch, and there no need to setup webserver everytime.